# django_filter ModelMultipleChoiceFilter - Bad Request on miss

Tags: django, django-filter

I have a `ViewSet` that has a `filter_class` that is like this:

```
class OrderFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    ......
    product = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        field_name='product',
        queryset=Product.objects.all(),
    )
```

With this, I can specify a product id, and make a get request like this `/orders/?product=<product_id>`.

I'm seeing the following behavior in three situations:

- If there are order(s) with the given `product_id`, it will return those orders ... good!
- If there are *NO* orders with that given `product_id`, it will return a successful 200, with an empty results (e.g. `{count: 0, next: null, previous: null, results: [ ]}` ... good!
- If that product_id doesn't *exist*, it returns a `400 Bad Request` with a `ValidationError` and this response:
  `{ product: [ "Select a valid choice. %(value)s is not one of the available choices." ]}` ... wtf!

This last situation seems odd to me.  Shouldn't the response be the same if (a) the given object relationship isn't there and (b) the object itself doesn't exist? This dual behavior would seemingly indicate to the FE if that product exists or not, and perhaps they shouldn't know that information.

How can I change my filters such that it *always* returns a 200 with a result set that is empty in those two cases?

I'm on `Django==1.11.15` and `django-filter==2.0.0`

Thanks!

Comment: does your `Product` model has a choices parameter?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, and the error message you provided looks like the one you get when you try to use an invalid choice as declared in the field's choices

Comment: no, the `id` in question is a primary key, it's not a choices/enum kinda thing.

Comment: but according to the docs `field_name` is the model field to filter against. Does your `Product` model have a field named `product` or am I missing something?